# How to handle conditional cflags with meson?

Tags: build, build-system, meson-build

I'm new to meson, just looking through the documentation at this point. What is your recommended way of handling conditional cflags in a meson build?

Say for Visual Studio I want to use /DNOMINMAX and a suppress a bunch of warnings only VS produces like /wd4626 /wd4640, etc. How would you suggest doing this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I solved this using a directory hierarchy and meson calls to get compiler version.

In my project root directory, I have a subdirectory for configuration stuff called `_meson`.

```
_meson/
      meson.build 
      compilers/
               meson.build 
               clang/
                     meson.build
                     7.0/
                         meson.build
               gcc/
                     meson.build
                     4.9/
                         meson.build
               msvc/
                     meson.build 
                     vs2015/
                            meson.build
                     vs2010/
                            meson.build
```

The root `meson.build` calls `subdir('_meson')` to include the configurations.

The `_meson/meson.build` calls `subdir('compilers')` to pull in configuration about compilers - the extra layer is in case I have platform specific configurations to add later.

Then `_meson/compilers/meson.build` looks like:

```
compiler_info = meson.get_compiler('cpp')

compiler = compiler_info.get_id()
compiler_version = compiler_info.version().split('-').get(0)

# setup some variables for compiler configurations
compiler_version_major = compiler_version.split('.').get(0)
compiler_version_minor = compiler_version.split('.').get(1)
compiler_version_build = compiler_version.split('.').get(2)

# load compiler configurations
subdir(compiler)
```

The last line directs meson to include the subdirectory with the same name as the compiler. So when compiling with gcc, this would evaluate to subdir('gcc').

This `meson.build` is where configuration information for *all* versions of that compiler would go. This file might look like:

```
# Put config information here...

# Include version specific configuration 
subdir(compiler_version_major + '.' + compiler_version_minor)
```

The subdirectories under the compiler name would contain configuration information for specific compiler versions, should they need some flags/config not all versions of the compiler support.

If possible, it would be helpful to make the `subdir()` conditional on the existence of the directory so the build doesn't break when building with a different specific build of the compiler.

**Caveat: I don't have meson running on windows yet, so I can't be sure the version string has 3 parts like it does for clang and gcc.**